# How can I place text over an image in a table cell?

Tags: html

I have the following code which produces cells in rows that are fit to the size of  the browser window:

```
<td><a href="URL1"><img src="IMG1"></a>TXT1</td>
<td><a href="URL2"><img src="IMG2"></a>TXT2</td>
<td><a href="URL3"><img src="IMG3"></a>TXT3</td>
```

I have over a hundred of these lines produced by a PHP loop.

I need the TXT1, TXT2, TXT3, etc. to be over their image.  However I also need the cells to be distributed the same as they are now (in rows that adjust to the width of the browser window).

Comment: So use percentage widths.

Comment: Adding `<table  style='table-layout:fixed;'>` and `</table>` puts all my cells on one row that extends well beyond the width of the browser window.

Comment: So make multiple rows.  Or look into `flex-wrap`.

Comment: Thanks!  `flex-wrap` adjusts the cells per row depending on browser window width just like I wanted.  However the text is still displaying underneath each image instead of on top.  And I don't know how to center the entire thing on the page.  `<center>` doesn't do anything.

Comment: `justify-content`

Comment: Awesome!  Just one last thing!  How do I get the text over the images instead of beneath them?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `display: flex` with `flex-wrap` to wrap rows based on the browser width.

Use `justify-content` and `align-items` to align them (see a flex tutorial for more details).

To position text over the image, wrap each image in a `position: relative` container, then make the text `position: absolute` and set `top` and `left` to position it within the container.